# Configure three screens backed by two graphic chips in a laptop under Linux

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display

I'd like to connect two external monitors (one via HDMI, one via VGA) to my [HP ProBook 4330s LW813EA](http://notebook.tech-details.com/HP_ProBook_4330s_%28LW813EA%29/#spec) laptop, while **keeping the laptop screen on** as well. The **Intel HD 3000** graphics embedded in [Core i5-2430M](http://ark.intel.com/products/53450/Intel-Core-i5-2430M-Processor-%283M-Cache-2_40-GHz%29) only supports **two** displays, but the laptop features an additional **ATI Radeon HD 6490M** chip. So far I used to keep it disabled, but I figure it could be possible to have it join forces with **HD 3000** in order to support all three screens.

What should I do to make it work under **Linux**? Simply turning the discrete graphics on did not help; I guess I'm gonna need some special driver support for this.

Note: I'm currently running kernel 3.12, but am willing to change it if that's what it takes.